# How inject list of bean in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I try to implement chain of responsibility with quarkus 2.10.0.

I have class IssueChangeChain and no one IssueChangeChainLink doesn't inject in field links.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class IssueChangeChain {

    @Inject
    @All
    List<IssueChangeChainLink> links;

    public void processIssueChange(JiraChangeDTO change) {
        logger.info("Try to process " + change + " through " + links);
        if(change == null)
            return;

        links.forEach(link ->{
            var changeItem = link.getChangeItem(change);
            if (changeItem != null) {
                link.processChangeItem(changeItem);
            }
        });

    }

    void setLinks(List<IssueChangeChainLink> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }
}
```

And three classes implemented IssueChangeChainLink

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class IssueCreationChainLink implements IssueChangeChainLink<AddJiraIssueDTO> {
    

    @Override
    public AddJiraIssueDTO getChangeItem(JiraChangeDTO change) {
...
    }

    @Override
    public void processChangeItem(AddJiraIssueDTO changeItem) {
...
    }

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IssueCreationChainLink.class);

}
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SprintChangeChainLink implements IssueChangeChainLink<IssueAddSprintDTO> {
    @Override
    public IssueAddSprintDTO getChangeItem(JiraChangeDTO change) {
...
    }

    @Override
    public void processChangeItem(IssueAddSprintDTO changeItem) {
...
    }

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SprintChangeChainLink.class);

}
```

What should I do to inject List of beans?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @geoand I have no errors. I've got only empty List of links.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Inject
List<?> instances;
```

does not work in Quarkus as this is not supported in CDI. In CDI it is looking for a bean which is a `List`.
What you should do is inject

```java
@Inject
@All
Instance<IssueChangeChainLink> instances;
```

`Instance` from CDI implements `Iterable`, which you can then use `.stream()` or `.forEach()` from to iterate over beans.

Comment: In [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#injecting-multiple-bean-instances-intuitively) wrote that it should be worked

Comment: In documentation is wrote that this way should work https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#injecting-multiple-bean-instances-intuitively

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see the actual interface. So your problem is that CDI takes type parameters as qualifiers. Because your instance is parametrised, i.e. 
```java
IssueChangeChainLink<IssueAddSprintDTO>
``` 
and 
```java
IssueChangeChainLink<AddJiraIssueDTO> 
```
you can use 
```java
@All
@Inject
List<IssueChangeChainLink<IssueAddSprintDTO>> instances;
```
but you can not inject all interfaces of type without type parameters.